# Registreing for AzureDNS preview

Tags: azure, dns

We have a subscription with Azure and we are using most of the services provided by Azure. Now we are trying to use the azurednspreview feature for managing our public DNS using Microsoft azure infrastructure.

We have used following two commands to register with the dns service.

Register-AzureProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Network -Force
Register-AzureProviderFeature -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Network -FeatureName azurednspreview -Force

After registering for the service, we tried to see the status using below command.

Get-AzureProviderFeature -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Network -FeatureName azurednspreview

As per the blog, the time for completing the registration is 24 hours and after that there will be a status as "Registered".

We made the request yesterday and 24 hours is finished, but still showing status as "Pending".

Could anyone tell us the reason for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would just wait a bit more, it will be activated.